# Cannot connect on TFS 2012 server through SSL with invalid certificate

Tags: apache-2.2, windows-server-2008-r2, team-foundation-server, ubuntu-12.04

I saw the problem on some forums and even here, but not as specific as mine. 
So here's the thing,

So I've configured a TFS 2012 server, on one of my personnel server at home, and now, I'm trying to make it available through the internet, with the help of apache2 on a different UNIX based, physical server. The thing is working perfectly, I don't have any problem accessing the address https://tfs.something.com/tfs through my browser. The address can be pinged and I do have access to the TFS control panel through it.

How does it work? Well, with apache2 you can set a virtual host and set up the ProxyPass and ProxyPassReserver setting, so the traffic can externally comes from a secure SSL connection, through a specified domain or sub-domain, but it can be locally redirect on a clear http session on a different port. This is my current setup.

As I already said, I can access the web interface, but when I'm trying to connect with Visual Studio 2012, it can't be done. Here's the error I receive:

[image: Error message]

The technical information says: `The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel.`

My SSL certificate is invalid and was automatically generated on my UNIX server. Even if I try to add it in the Trusted Root Certification Authorities either on my TFS server or on my local workstation, it doesn't work. I still receive the same error.

Is there's a way to completely ignore certificate validation? If not, what's have I done? I mean, I've added the certificate in the trusted root certificates, it should works as mentioned on some forums...

If you need more information, please ask me, I'll be pleased to provide you more.
Dave

Comment: [Please take a moment to read our FAQ.](http://serverfault.com/faq)  Your question appears off-topic for this site to me.

Comment: Thanks and I'm sorry, I though it would be interesting to the community to know how to bypass SSL certification verification on Windows with TFS.

Comment: Don't apologize, just my opinion.  And not a very strong one either, since I didn't vote to close it or downvote it.  Seemed interesting enough to have around to me too, honestly... just wanted to make sure you read the FAQ more than anything else, and your question made me suspect you hadn't.

Comment: I will be sincere and indeed, I didn't read this part of the FAQ, I though it was the same as the one on Stack Overflow, which I already read.

Comment: Honesty *and* willingness to admit making a mistake?  You're a rare one.  Have an upvote, since I don't have an answer to give.

Comment: Thank you very much! :) I hope someone will be able to help me!

Answer (score 1):

If you go to the URL with Internet Explorer you can see if it should work for Visual Studio. If IE opens the site without any certificate warnings then VS should be able to do so as well.

Make sure when you add the certificate to your client machine that you manually select the Trusted Root certificate store; I have found that it doesn't always put it in the right place if you allow it to select the store automatically.

Finally, your certificate must have valid dates and the name must match the URL used. (it is ok to be self-signed since you are going to explicitly trust it.) if either of these are incorrect then neither IE or VS will work as desired.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried clearing the cache on the VS client? Follow steps in this MSDN article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa833872.aspx#ConfigClient